# Ruby on Rails: why does the content of each child print out when I iterate over them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have the following models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ratings
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

I also have the following code in the question's show.html.erb file:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @question.name %>
</p>

<% if @ratings.blank? %>
    <p>There are no ratings for this question.</p>
<% else %>
    <ul>
        <%= @ratings.each do |rating| %>
            <li>
                <%= rating.name %>
                <%= link_to "Show", rating %>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(@question) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', questions_path %>
```

The relevant questions_controller.rb entry is as follows:

```
def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  @ratings = Rating.where(question_id: @question.id)
  respond_with(@question)
end
```

I can't for the life of me see why the output contains the contents of the child objects, as well as just the unordered list items that I've created in my iteration.  Any thoughts?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove the `=` in this line: `<%= @ratings.each do |rating| %>`

Comment: Oh for ... Many thanks, it's *ALWAYS* the simplest things you overlook!

Comment: At least you know you will never fall for this again :)

Comment: Well if I do, hopefully I'll find my own question on SO! :D

Answer (score -1):

Use - but = in your each loop

```
- @pages.each do |x|
 p = x.id
 p = x.xx
```

This is what you want.

Also, I recommend you to use slim as a replacement of erb.

Comment: in ERB the `-` is optional, and the slim recommendation is completely unwarranted.